# How should backend application respond to error or invalid input?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We are creating an app for iOS and have chosen Java running on Google App Engine for the backend. We use Google Cloud Endpoints to generate client library for iOS. We are relatively new to most of this and we are not quite sure how the backend should respond after an error based on user action. For example we have a method for creating a custom user, which should return the user-object if the save was successful. But there may be conditions that are not met and if so the app must get an appropriate response and handle present to the user. This is how we thought of doing it:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "createUser", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public User createUser(User user) throws BadRequestException
{
    if(!validateUsername(user.getUsername()))
        throw new BadRequestException("Invalid characters in username");

    //Do stuff and save user
    .........

    return user
}
```

And then maybe throw a custom exception derived from ServiceException if the username exists etc. Is this a reasonable way to do it? I just feel like it's a little brutal to be throwing exceptions every time something like this happens. It also also appears in the log which could make it difficult to distinguish between actual application errors that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Google App Engine but for me it reads like that the BadRequestException thrown is handled on an upper level like expected by returning a 400 Bad Request HTTP Response as intended (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions). So yes it seems the right way to throw this exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach for throwing error 400 (`BadRequestException`) is fine in this case.

Additionally, Endpoints also provides other exceptions like UnauthorizedException (401), ForbiddenException(403), etc. Check out the [list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions).

You can also have custom Exceptions that you can map to other HTTP codes that Endpoints supports. So your approach to have a Custom Exception is fine but do keep in mind that it will need to map to one of the HTTP codes eventually.

When it comes to parsing out the response in the client and doing some custom processing based on the error, it could get trickly, since all the control that you have to set the specific details are limited to the `message` attribute. So you will need to hack out the message format in such a way that you can parse and figure out what to do.